# insert spinner value in mysql db via soap ws in android

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-spinner, android-ksoap2

Hi i have to develop the app is insert the database from spinner in mysql database via soap webserices in android application...

i have use below webservice code:

```
public class Insertion {

 public String insertData(String userName,String userPassword){

 try{

 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/androidlogin","root","");
 PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user(status) VALUES ('"+userName+"');");
  int result = statement.executeUpdate();
   }

    catch(Exception exc){
     System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }

      return "Insertion successfull!!";
      }

   }
```

i have use below code for android spinner example:

```
  public class InsertionExample extends Activity{
  private final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
  private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8085/XcartLogin/services/Insertion?wsdl";
  private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/insertData";
  private final String METHOD_NAME = "insertData";
  Button btninsert;
  private Spinner spnMusketeers;
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    btninsert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_insert);  
    btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         insertValues();
        }
    });
  }

  public void insertValues(){


    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    Spinner userName = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnMusketeers);
    List<String> lsMusketeers = new ArrayList<String>();
    lsMusketeers.add("Q");
    lsMusketeers.add("P");
    lsMusketeers.add("C");

    ArrayAdapter<String> aspnMusketeers = 
      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
       lsMusketeers);
    aspnMusketeers.setDropDownViewResource
       (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spnMusketeers.setAdapter(aspnMusketeers);

// Set up a callback for the spinner
   spnMusketeers.setOnItemSelectedListener(
    new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, 
         int position, long id)  {

          // Code that does something when the Spinner value changes
        }

    });
    String user_Name = userName.getContext().toString();


    //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
       PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
       unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
       unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//Define value for fname variable
       unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
       request.addProperty(unameProp);


         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
         HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

         try{
          androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
             SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

             TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
             result.setText(response.toString());

      }
      catch(Exception e){

      } 
       // Code that does something when the Spinner value changes
     }
     }
```

Here how is change my code for this question.

my logcat window says:

```
  08-23 02:48:40.030: D/AndroidRuntime(4055): Shutting down VM
  08-23 02:48:40.030: W/dalvikvm(4055): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
  08-23 02:48:40.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4055): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  08-23 02:48:40.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4055): java.lang.NullPointerException
  08-23 02:48:40.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4055):   at com.android.soap.InsertionExample.insertValues(InsertionExample.java:63)
   08-23 02:48:40.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4055):  at com.android.soap.InsertionExample$1.onClick(InsertionExample.java:43)
   08-23 02:48:40.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4055):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    08-23 02:48:40.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4055):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
   08-23 02:48:40.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4055):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
   08-23 02:48:40.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4055):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   08-23 02:48:40.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4055):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  08-23 02:48:40.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4055):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
  08-23 02:48:40.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4055):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   08-23 02:48:40.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4055):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
   08-23 02:48:40.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4055):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    08-23 02:48:40.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4055):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
   08-23 02:48:40.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4055):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help me....what error is occurred here.give me solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code for this insert function:

```
String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
```